# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException (100 day of Python boot camp Angela Yu)

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, try-except

I am trying to do an Automated LinkedIn job application as part of the Bootcamp 100 days of Python. The purpose of this boot is to skip all the applications that need more than 1 step by filtering them by those with easy applications and which just need the phone number to be written. Right now, I have been able to click on all the job posts, click the easy application button and close the pop-up window when the application button says "Next". However, when I want to write a phone number and click on the submit application button my code crashes. In all the cases, when the pop-up window has a submit application button the exception is raised. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
for element in all_jobs_:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
    element.click()
    time.sleep(10)  # wait for 2 seconds for the page to respond to the click

    try:
        # Click on easy apply button of list first element
        easy_apply_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.jobs-apply-button")
        easy_apply_button.click()
        time.sleep(10)  # wait for 10 seconds for the page to respond to the click

        next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.artdeco-button--primary")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)

        # find the button using the CSS selector and aria-label attribute
        button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[aria-label="Continue to next step"]')

        # get the text of the button
        button_text = button.get_attribute('innerText')

        if button_text == "Next":
            close_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-button--circle")
            close_button.click()
            discard_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-button--secondary")
            discard_button.click()
            print("No application button, skipped.")
            continue

        else:
            ##filling the phone texbox
            phone_textbox = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.artdeco-text-input--type-text")
            phone_textbox.send_keys(phone)

            #find the submit aplication button using the CSS selector and aria-label attribute
            submit_application_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-button--primary")
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", submit_application_button)
            submit_application_button.click()

        close_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.artdeco-button--circle")
        close_button.click()

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Exception")
        continue
```

I already tried to find the text box element using different css selectors, like its class, its parent html element class, and so on but same results.